# assign a new column based on certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I need a way to apply different conditions on it. If points < 20 then `very low`
points > 20 and < 80 then `low`
points > 80 and less than <=150 `medium`
points > 150 then `high`

```
     Points
0     10
1     08
2     25
3     40
4     90
5    150
6    350
```

desired output:

```
     Points     new
0     10     very low
1     08     very low
2     25          low
3     40          low
4     90       medium
5    150       medium
6    350         High
```

I was able to solve it with a function and few if conditions but I'm looking for a better pandas approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `cut`

```
pd.cut(df.Points,bins=[0,20,80,150,999],labels=['very low','low','medium','High'])
Out[64]: 
0    very low
1    very low
2         low
3         low
4      medium
5      medium
6        High
Name: Points, dtype: category
#df['new']=pd.cut(df.Points,bins=[0,20,80,150,999],labels=['very low','low','medium','High'])
```

Comment: It works! Thank you and one question why are there five bins and only four labels? How does it work?

Comment: @SaiKumar bins mean;s the boundary , which is 0-20 20-80 80-150 150-999

Comment: Got it. In my question I mentioned `<=150` to be medium but what If I want `<150` to be medium and `>=150` to be higher

Comment: @SaiKumar check out the site https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html, you can pick the `right=True` or not .. :-)

Comment: @BENY Is there a way to put these bins where one doesn't know the upper limit of the bin? or the lower limit of the bin? Taking the question example, what if we do not know how far >150 the data might go? So, how will we put the last bin edge 999?

Comment: @Meet pd.cut(df.Points,bins=[0,20,80,150,np.Inf],labels=['very low','low','medium','High'])

Comment: Oh. I was needlessly searching for an argument to use. Quite a simple solution to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.select`:

```
import numpy as np

conds = [df.Points < 20, df.Points < 80, df.Points <=150]

choices = ['very low', 'low', 'medium']

df['new'] = np.select(conds, choices, default = 'high')

>>> df
   Points       new
0      10  very low
1       8  very low
2      25       low
3      40       low
4      90    medium
5     150    medium
6     350      high
```

Note: If you want to avoid explicitely importing `numpy`, you can use `pd.np` as a wrapper:

```
df['new'] = pd.np.select(conds, choices, default = 'high')
```